# jqgrid differentiate in dataInit add and edit forms

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

How I can differentiate in the dataInit event wether am I adding new data or editing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a good question! +1 from me for it.

There are no direct way to detect inside of `dataInit` whether it is called from Add or Edit form. In the same way if you use multiple editing mode (like [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) and [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)) and multiple searching modes ([advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) dialog and [the searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching)) there are no direct way to detect in which place the control are used.

As the workaround you can use the following. You can define a variable which you can set in the different value inside of an event which will be called in both Add and Edit form **before** the `dataInit` will be called. To tell the trust you have not so large choice. It's the [beforeInitData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event only. So you can do like following

```
var myGrid = $("#list"),
    inEdit;

$("#list").jqGrid({
    // all parameters of the jqGrid definition
});
myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
  { del: false, search: false },
  { // Edit
      recreateForm: true,
      beforeInitData: function () {
          inEdit = true;
      }
  },
  { // Add
      recreateForm: true,
      beforeInitData: function () {
          inEdit = false;
      }
  });
```

I used [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property additionally to be sure that on every opening of the Add or Edit grid the form created new and the `dataInit` be called.

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithDataInitSourceDetect.htm) the Add form looks like

[image]

Here the `dataInit` for the "Notes" write just the text "in Add" in the corresponding control. The "Inv. No" is the field which hold the id. The corresponding `<input>` control of the Add/Edit form is disabled. So the user can't make any changes. In case of "Add" dialog the method `$.jgrid.randId()` will be used to generate new unique id value.

The corresponding Edit form are like on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks, Oleg! I wish to have enough reputation to vote up your answer :(

Comment: @diosney: You are welcome! If you don't forgot you can vote the old helpful answers later after you will have 15 points of reputations. Your first question was good, if you will continue so you will soon have much more reputation points as 15. I have enough reputations. The most important to vote up good questions or answers to place there higher in the searching results. So the answer could help other people too.

Comment: @Tareq: You are welcome! I am glad to read that the answer help you.

Comment: @Oleg: What are you ? Saved my day all over again.