# changing edit options specifically dataEvents on edit form jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

My colmodel, has a column name'count' and a editoptions dataEvent that alerts a change.
In the add form i want to remove this alert and need this alert only in the edit mode..
So, i tried a couple of things in the add form beforeshowform(),using setColProp and .attr 
 But nothing seems to work.. any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting of [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) inside of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) is too late. You should make the changes inside of `beforeInitData` callback.

If you would need additionally to use different initializations inside of `dataInit` you can use the simple trick which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974432/315935). In the case you just set any variable like `inEdit` to `true` or `false` and inside of `beforeInitData` callback and make different actions inside of `dataInit` depend in the value of `inEdit`.